# How do I find "origin" of a Date in R

Tags: r, date

If I have a date that i've converted using the as.Date function, e.g. `"2015-01-01"` how can I find out what date it is using as reference for its origin? And yes, I tried `?Date`, and tried using the default origin, but got days in 1945. I would like to know how to do this generally so I don't have to manually check every time I do operations on dates.

Comment: Like this? `as.Date("2015-01-01") - as.numeric(as.Date("2015-01-01"))`. Can you `dput()` the date object that has the usual origin? Can you show exactly what code you ran?

Comment: From `?Date`: "Dates are represented as the number of days since 1970-01-01." So, if it's a `Date` class object, that's the origin.

Comment: Which is to say, a non-standard origin isn't saved, it's just converted to the usual origin: `as.numeric(as.Date(0, origin = as.Date("2015-05-08")))` gives 16563, same as `as.numeric(Sys.Date())`

Comment: So it is 1970. I guessed that based off of the results I was getting, but some other factors lead to that not making sense to me, so I wanted to inquire around first. I googled a little, and they said the default origin was 1900-01-01, which is obviously wrong. So, I think I'm fine now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As described in the documentation, the `origin` argument does not create a corresponding attribute in the `Date` object; it's just to make input easier from integers (e.g., from Excel, SAS, etc. that use different origins).

A `dput` confirms that `Date`s are plain old numbers:

```
d <- as.Date("2000-01-01")
dput(d)
# structure(10957, class = "Date")
```

(I'd use `str(d)` instead, but that sometimes seems to hide information.)

Answer (score 13):

R package `lubridate` has a solution. `lubridate::origin` will return what origin is for you.

Comment: WIndows and Macs used to have different date origins (I don't know if they still do).  Does lubridate::origin give you different results on a Windows machine vs a Mac?