# can't use mutate with a DATE

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this database:

```
structure(list(id_mujer = c(8528, 8528, 11711, 11711, 11818,

11818), hpv_post = structure(c(1339459200, 1458172800, 1443571200,

1443571200, 1354838400, 1525392000), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct",

"POSIXt")), hpv_post_res = c("NEG", "NEG", "POS", "POS", "NEG",

"NEG")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"

))
```

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3

id_mujer hpv_post hpv_post_res

<dbl> <dttm> <chr>

1 8528 2012-06-12 00:00:00 NEG

2 8528 2016-03-17 00:00:00 NEG

3 11711 2015-09-30 00:00:00 POS

4 11711 2015-09-30 00:00:00 POS

5 11818 2012-12-07 00:00:00 NEG

6 11818 2018-05-04 00:00:00 NEG
```

I need to create a column called "positive" where the hpv_post_res of an observation is "POS" put the hpv_post of that observation, and if not a 0. The problem is that when I do this:

```
base_contactos_3 %>%

mutate(positivo= if_else(hpv_post_res=="POS", hpv_post, 0))
```

For some reason I get this error:

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `positivo`.

i `positivo = if_else(hpv_post_res == "POS", hpv_post, 0)`.

x 'origin' must be supplied

Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

When a say that if the condition is false put a 0 is only because i dont know what to do and it is not transcendent. But if instead of a 0 i put a string like:

```
base_contactos_3 %>%

mutate(positivo= if_else(hpv_post_res=="POS", hpv_post, "negative"))
```

It gives me this error:

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `positivo`.

i `positivo = if_else(hpv_post_res == "POS", hpv_post, "negative")`.

x `false` must be a `POSIXct/POSIXt` object, not a character vector.

Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

And if a put a NA instead of a 0 (which is the option i prefer) it gives me this error:

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `positivo`.

i `positivo = if_else(hpv_post_res == "POS", hpv_post, NA)`.

x `false` must be a `POSIXct/POSIXt` object, not a logical vector.

Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is telling you the reason :
The column you "want to mutate" is character type "POS" if TRUE but if FALSE you are providing date. thats why if you give a character it works.

1st idea that worked for me: if you don't find it useful, please let me know.

```
 base_contactos_3%>%
  mutate(positivo= if_else(hpv_post_res=="POS", as.character(hpv_post), as.character(0)))
```

gives the following result.
Since you are merging date and character as choices for TRUE/FALSE, you can have only 1 in resulting column. (Since time is 0 only so only dates are taken)

```
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  id_mujer hpv_post            hpv_post_res positivo  
     <dbl> <dttm>              <chr>        <chr>     
1     8528 2012-06-12 00:00:00 NEG          0         
2     8528 2016-03-17 00:00:00 NEG          0         
3    11711 2015-09-30 00:00:00 POS          2015-09-30
4    11711 2015-09-30 00:00:00 POS          2015-09-30
5    11818 2012-12-07 00:00:00 NEG          0         
6    11818 2018-05-04 00:00:00 NEG          0
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! Apply an as.character to a date like hpv post 
will not change the content of the variable? Will the data remain the same?

Comment: original data is not changed since as.character is applied in the mutated new column to get the result. I have posted the output as well. Yes if you apply as. chartacter() to original column itself , then data type will change from dttm to char.  If this has helped you please mark it accepted. will help others too.

Comment: Pls accept the answer and close it.

Answer (score 1):

There are two causes to your problem:

- Every entry in a column of a data frame needs to be of the same type.
- `if_else` requires that the yes and no outputs have the same type (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50646133/dplyr-if-else-vs-base-r-ifelse)).

Each of your attempts fails for some combination of these two reasons:

1. `if_else(hpv_post_res == "POS", hpv_post, 0)` identifies that the output is type date. As zero is not a date it tries to convert 0 to a date. If an origin date exists then it can convert numeric values to dates. But there is no origin, hence it errors.
2. `if_else(hpv_post_res == "POS", hpv_post, "negative")` is trying to output both date and string types. `if_else` will not permit this.
3. `if_else(hpv_post_res == "POS", hpv_post, NA)` would work in most instances as columns of a data frame can take values and `NA`. But in the strictest sense `NA` is of type logical. Hence, the error.

Solution options:

- As **@anuanand** suggests you can convert to character.
- `ifelse` is similar to `if_else` but does not require data types to be identical. However, it converts dates to numeric. So this would be a solution if your input column was not of type date.
- Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39648545/7742981) solution you can find out what the origin is. You can then use the `ifelse` approach: `as.Date(ifelse(hpv_post_res == "POS", hpv_post, NA), origin = lubridate::origin())`.
- if you are willing to step outside of dplyr you can use logical indexing:

```r
base_contactos_3$positivo = base_contactos_3$hpv_post
base_contactos_3$positivo[base_contactos_3$hpv_post_res != "POS"] = NA
```

Comment: I chose anuanand's option because ifelse I can't use it since I work with dates and either because I need to use dplyr.
But if I try to use origins() it doesn't work: 
base_contactos_3 %>%
+   mutate(positivo= as.Date(ifelse(hpv_post_res == "POS", hpv_post, NA), 
+                                    origin = lubridate::origin())) 
Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `positivo`.
i `positivo = as.Date(ifelse(hpv_post_res == "POS", hpv_post, NA), origin = lubridate::origin())`.
x tentativa de aplicar una no-función
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: Thanks. Then please accept it as an answer.  Only suggestion is keep things simple even if very smart syntax are available @juandmaz  also another of your question though closed but i like the way you share reproducible data with structure(list...).  We can just copy paste to recreate.

Answer (score 1):

See @SimonSA’s excellent answer explaining why this is happening.

An additional solution, if you want to keep `positivo` as a datetime and use `NA`s, is to coerce `NA` to a datetime using `as.POSIXct()`:

```
library(tidyverse)

base_contactos_3 %>%
  mutate(positivo = if_else(
    hpv_post_res == "POS", 
    hpv_post, 
    as.POSIXct(NA)
  ))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  id_mujer hpv_post            hpv_post_res positivo           
     <dbl> <dttm>              <chr>        <dttm>             
1     8528 2012-06-12 00:00:00 NEG          NA                 
2     8528 2016-03-17 00:00:00 NEG          NA                 
3    11711 2015-09-30 00:00:00 POS          2015-09-30 00:00:00
4    11711 2015-09-30 00:00:00 POS          2015-09-30 00:00:00
5    11818 2012-12-07 00:00:00 NEG          NA                 
6    11818 2018-05-04 00:00:00 NEG          NA
```

As a shortcut, the lubridate package provides an `NA_POSIXct_` type you can use for the same result:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

base_contactos_3 %>%
  mutate(positivo = if_else(
    hpv_post_res == "POS", 
    hpv_post, 
    NA_POSIXct_
  ))
```